# Can't get data in edit form

Tags: django

I'm trying to create an edit form for existing users, I have the User model and I associated to it a profile.
The problem is that the fields of profile are empty in the rendered html, however when I created a new user I filled these fields, and when I enter to administration I find the fields are filled.
[image]
models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profile(models.Model):
    DEPARTMENT_CHOICES = (('MI', 'Math et info'),
                          ('ST', 'Science et Tech'),
                          ('SM', 'Science de la matiere'))

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=35, choices=DEPARTMENT_CHOICES, blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile-images', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

views.py

```
def profile_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = EditUserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        ins = Profile.objects.get(pk=5)
        profile_form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=ins)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            if 'picture' in request.FILES:
                profile.picture = request.FILES['picture']

            profile.save()
            return redirect(home)
    else:
        user_form = EditUserForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = EditProfileForm(request.FILES, instance=request.user)

    return render(request, 'account/profile.html', {'user_form': user_form,
                                                    'profile_form': profile_form})
```

forms.py

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('description', 'department', 'picture', )


class EditUserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', )
```

profile.html

```
{% extends 'manhal/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="col-md-6">

            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'profile' %}" class="form-horizontal">{% csrf_token %}

                <fieldset>
                    <legend>User Profile</legend>

                    {{ user_form|crispy }}
                    {{ profile_form|crispy}}
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">
                </fieldset>
            </form>

    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Don't pass request.POST in the else block.

Comment: is still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your if/else block is checking if the request is a `POST`. Since the `else` block is not a `POST`, you do not want to pass any `POST` data into your form. This will make the form think it's bound with no data.

Also, it looks like you are passing the `request.user` to your `ProfileForm` as the instance, but the model on the `ProfileForm` meta class is expecting a `Profile` object.

Can you fix those two things and see if it works or not? If it doesn't work, please post some more code (like your templates).

Comment: I did what you told me, but still doesn't work. @Esteban

Comment: You also need to remove the `request.Files` and pass in the correct instance:
`profile_form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)`